# Calculating total mass of a wire

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm giving the following 
$$
\delta(x) = x + 7,\quad (0 \leq x \leq 4) 
$$
It says  you are given the length-density function, $\delta(x)$, of an ininfinitesimally thin wire lying on the $x$-axis over a given interval. calculate the total mass of the wire.

The answer given is $1/3$. I've been trying to look online for a way to do this problem but no luck. The only problem similar to this one in my book is 
$$
  \delta(x)= x\ln(x),\quad (3 \leq x \leq 9) 
$$
And it seems like they just integrated this from $3$ to $9$. But I get a different answer than the one giving to me when I do it this way for the one on top. Wondering if you guys can help push me into the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: The mass is not $1/3$, since $\int_0^4 (x+7)\,dx$ is much larger than that.

Comment: I'm getting an answer of $36$ with a quick mental calculation.

Comment: I'm also getting 36. Not sure why in the book it says 1/3.